# VBA to Delete a Folder irrespective of any User

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Macro to create a Folder in Desktop irrespective of any user, But need a code to delete the same folder from Desktop, irrespective of any user.

```
MkDir CreateObject("wscript.shell").SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Output File"
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win004.htm

Comment: Thanks but the examples shwon are with specific path name. Say if I'm sharing this file with another person and the path name will be different for him. So the vba should delet the folder from Desktop for any user.

Comment: *You already have the path in your posted line of code*, so I'm unclear exactly what the problem is here?

Comment: replace `MkDir` with `RmDir` and this line will remove the folder instead of creating it. `DeleteExample4` of the posted link by the way. If you want to delete this for **every** user you will Ⓐ need to figure out all the user names first so you can loop through and Ⓑ need admin privileges to delete something on foreign users profile.